# Azure powershell session instantly times out

Tags: azure, azure-caching, azure-powershell

I am trying to create an Azure Managed Cache using the Azure Powershell now that the ability to create this in the management GUI has been removed.

Using Add-AzureAccount I am able to log in to Azure with my usual credentials.  As soon as I issue the command to create the cache:

```
New-AzureManagedCache -Name mycachename -Location "North Europe" -Sku Basic -Memory 128MB
```

... I immediately get the error:

```
    New-AzureManagedCache : Your Windows Azure credential in the Windows PowerShell session has expired. Please use Add-AzureAccount to login again.
    At line:1 char:1
+ New-AzureManagedCache -Name mycachename -Location "North Europe" -Sku Basic -Memory 128MB
    + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [New-AzureManagedCache], AadAuthenticationCantRenewException
        + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ManagedCache.NewAzureManagedCache
```

If I log in again I get the same error and am going round in circles.

This is using a Free Trial which is absent of Azure tech support so any suggestions gratefully received.  Azure Service status is showing all OK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see if the guidance provided here might help: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsazure/en-US/260df055-7c4e-4ce2-8f8d-190ad20a4b76/cant-get-azure-credentials-to-stick-in-powershell?forum=windowsazuresecurity

Comment: Thanks for the link Simon.  The problem was that Azure Powershell was getting accounts mixed up.